# Getting error: unexpected token: "antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token:

Tags: java, sql

This is the query I have written

```
public Map<Integer, String> getData(Set<Integer> ids, LocalDate asOfDate, Boolean flag) {
    return em.createQuery("SELECT CI.class_id as id, T.div_data as division " +
                    "FROM class_information CI " +
                    "INNER JOIN division_info DI ON CI.class_id = DI.class_id " +
                    "INNER JOIN div_data DD ON DI.roll_no = DD.roll_no" +
                    "WHERE case when (:flag = true) then DD.is_present = true else DD.is_present = false end " +
                    "AND CI.class_id IN :ids AND :asOfDate " +
                    "BETWEEN CI.start_date AND CI.end_date AND :asOfDate " +
                    "BETWEEN DD.start_date AND DD.end_date", Tuple.class)
            .setParameter("asOfDate", asOfDate)
            .setParameter("ids", ids)
            .setParameter("flag", flag).getResultList()
            .stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            tuple -> ((Integer) tuple.get("id")),
                            tuple -> ((String) tuple.get("division")))
            );
}
```

I am getting these errors:

```
unexpected token: ="antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: =
unexpected token: else"antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: else
unexpected token: DD"antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: DD
```

I am unable to understand why these errors are coming and how to resolve them. Could anybody give a solution here?

Comment: That use of the `flag` parameter is weird. Wouldn't it be clearer if you did `WHERE DD.is_present = :flag`?

Comment: I think this is not SQL but JPQL, and if you look [there](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.2/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_case_expressions), you will see that `x=true` is not a thing you can do in the when clause of a case expression, but you can write it as another case expression